# Registering click events for emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp

I want to register a click event and do actions based on the `position`, `window` ..etc.

This site, `http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Click-Events.html`, shows the layout of the event variables, but how do I actually attach a handler to the click events.

So, basically I am looking for a function that behaves like `attach-handler` would in the below senario.

```
(attach-handler [mouse-1] 
       `(lambda (e) (foo e))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the code letter `e' of the `interactive` declaration to access the event; e.g., the following will make left click insert the event data at the point clicked:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<down-mouse-1>")
  (lambda (event)
    (interactive "e")
    (message "%s" event)
    (let ((posn (elt event 1)))
      (with-selected-window (posn-window posn)
        (goto-char (posn-point posn))
        (insert (format "%s" event))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

They are all keys. Try `C-h c` ( or `C-h k`) and click a mouse button to see what it is currently bound to. Then use `M-x global-set-key` to set it to whatever you want to. Your function will have to be `interactive` to bind it to a key.

Comment: Ok, so how would I get the `event` information in the following statement? 

`(global-set-key [mouse-1] \`(lambda() (interactive) (print event))`

Comment: Are you getting anything out of the `print`? You might want to create named function instead of a `lambda` and `edebug` it to see if event has any interesting properties. Also look at `last-input-event` and `last-command-event`. Oh and there is also `mouse-event-p` and others.